# Plotting two Event Labels in Google Analytics Dashboard

Tags: google-analytics

In the Dashboard of Google Analytics, it is possible to plot a graph of the number of events which belong to a specific category and have a specific label. So, for example, I have those two widgets on my Dashboard, showing me the number of total Events of Label A and Label B:
[image: Dasboard]

However, I would like to be able to see how Label A does compared to Label B, so it should plot those two graphs into one coordinate system. The “Top Events” view can do that almost, but it always shows the “Total Events” graph, which might be relatively large and therefore makes the coordinate system scale too large, making the other graphs too small to be good comparable:

[image: Top Events]

Is it possible to achieve that on the Dasboard, and is it also possible to remove the "Total Events" graph from the last picture, only plotting specific labels?

(Sorry, I needed to break up the image links since I have not enough reputation to post images, would be nice if someone could fix that, I think it is too difficult to explain it only with words)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s possible to get two events plotted on a chart with their own an appropriate axis.

You have to use the "*motion chart*" and go to its graph view. The motion chart button is on the top right beside the chart icon. When you click this, the chart view is the right-most tab on the top right of the chart.

To select exactly what you need charted, select the event types from the box to the right of the chart. The graph will resize to give you the best axes for your data.

Comment: How do you then get that on the dashboard? If I use 'add to dashboard' I get it as a table, not a graph